# Javascript - get current page URL without pagination numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, url

Say I have a URL for an article:

http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/

And it has about 5 pages, so as you go through each page, you get:

http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/ OR http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/1

http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/2

http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/3

http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/4

http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/5

I know that the following code will get the full current URL (aka including the page #):

```
var u = window.location.href;
```

But is there a way to limit it so that the page # is NOT a part of the variable "u"?

Perhaps there's a regex or something I should add in there..? (I'm fairly new to javascript, so not sure how to apply this?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var u = window.location.href.match(/.*[/][^\d]*/)[0]
```

Would that work for you?

#### Edit

I changed it... again :P

Comment: Rather than putting that `/` in a character class you could just escape it `\/`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Would something like `http://.*/` work in this example too?

Comment: @NullUserException I know... personal prefference for me.  Just makes it easier for me to read it.

Comment: @GNi33 Just tested that and it does work as long as you escape/place in a character class the `/`s

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should really take the time to learn Regular Expressions. Would need them all the time, but my knowledge about them is very limited

Comment: @GNi33 what little I know was worth my while and it was because of SO questions that I did learn what I have :P [This refference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) was handy too.

Answer (score 2):

> **NOTE:** Regex is a more complicated version of Joseph's and still suffers from the same bug. Will undelete when I fix it.

Joseph's answer is good, but it has a minor bug: it will drop the last part of the URL if you have an URL like:

http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here

You can use this instead:

```
var u = window.location.href.match(/(.*)(\/\d*)/)[1]
```

How the regex works:

```
/          # delimiter
(.*?)      # match anything and put in capture group 1
(\/        # match the forward slash
 \d*)      # match zero or more digits
/          # delimiter
```

Comment: That's what I just realized too.  Would your version of the code check that it's a number only?  (If you could translate the regex you entered, that would be super awesome!! :))

Comment: `"http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/".match(/.*[/]/)[0]`  Run it in a console. It works.

Comment: Perhaps something like "var u = window.location.href.match(/[0-9]\/?\d*/)[1]" ?

Comment: @Joseph It will. Try running `javascript:alert("http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here".match(/.*[/]/)[0])` on your browser's URL bar

Comment: ah but you changed your post.  And yes it will chop that off. Mine works according to the OPs expressed requirements

Answer (score 1):

```
var l = window.location;
l.href.replace(l.pathname, l.pathname.split(/\/[0-9]+$/)[0]);
```

[try it in the console at this URL](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2011/08/the-two-sides-of-social-networking-on-display-in-the-london-riots.ars/2)

Answer (score -1):

Regex would do it. But in this case, you could just turn it into an array, strip of the end item, and re-serialize it.

```
var a = 'http://domain.com/blog/articles/title-here/2'.split('/');
a.splice(-1, 1);
a.join('/');
```